# How to give a sign and exit infinitive loop when sending file via socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to send a text file from cleint and to write it on server side, but I am not sure how exit the infinitive while(true) loop. Here is my code which is very simple.

Client

```
byte[] msg = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\TCPIP\test_big.txt");
int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);
```

Server

```
while (true) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
    // Program is suspended while waiting for an incoming connection.
    Socket handler = listener.Accept();
    data = null;
    string outputPath = @"C:\output\2.txt";

    while (true) 
    {
        bytes = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
        data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
       //I need a "break;" here...
    }
    File.WriteAllText(outputPath, data);
    Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(outputPath) ? "File received." : "File not received.");

    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    handler.Close();

}
```

I used example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y0e13d3(v=vs.110).aspx)...

So, my question is, how to exit the while loop when I receive all the bytes?
Thanks.

Comment: In the MSDN example it waits until it receives an <EOF> marker which you've removed - so you need a similar way to denote an end of message

Comment: Yes, that is true. But I am not sure how to achieve that with a file. I can do that with the "data" but what if I am sending a huge file or a file which is not txt... @auburg

Comment: You can send a file, and then additionally send <EOF>

Comment: The problem is that my while loop will work only with byte[] msg. If that is done, I can work with anything else, like <EOF>, but how to reach that? That is the problem when sending in chunks and working with infinitive loop. @auburg

Comment: But you're converting the bytes to a string aren't you i.e. `data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,bytesRec);
                    if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1) {
                        break;
                    }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop reading incoming data if it is empty

```
while (true) 
{
    bytes = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);

    if(bytesRec <= 0)
        break;

    data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec); 
}
```